# Deal with large amount of strings to validation with two for-loop iteration

Tags: java, list, file

I'm facing this problem and kinda dont know how to deal with it. I need to process a csv file that can contain 100 or 100 thousand lines.

I need to do some validations before to proceed the processing, one of them is to check if each `document` has same `typeOfDoc`. Let me explain:

Content of file:

```
document;typeOfDoc
25693872076;2
25693872076;2
...
25693872076;1
```

This validations consists in check if to `document` has different type of `typeOfDoc` along the file, and if it is, show that's invalid.

Initially I thinked in two for-loop to iterate over first occurrence of `document` (which I assume that's correct, because I don't know what I'm going to receive), and for that correct `document` I iterate over the rest of file to verify if has another occurence of it, and if have same `document` but if  `typeOfDoc` is different of first occurence, I store this validation on a object to show that this file has one `document` with two different types. But.... you'll imagine where it is going. This can't happen with 100k lines, even with 100.

Which is the better way to do that?

Something that can help.

This is how I open and process the file *(`try-catch`, `close()`, and properly names were omitted)*:

```
List<String> lines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)).lines().skip(1).collect(Collectors.toList());

for (String line : lines) {
    String[] arr = line.split(";");
    String document = arr[0];
    String typeOfDoc = arr[1];
    for (String line2 : lines) {
        String[] arr2 = line2.split(";");
        String document2 = arr2[0];
        String typeOfDoc2 = arr2[1];
        if (document.equals(document2) && !typeOfDoc.equals(typeOfDoc2)) {
            ...create object to show that error on grid...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of ArrayList use a HashMap.  Make document the key and typeOfDoc the value of the HashMap. Use a single for loop, and check each time if the HashMap already has the key and different value. If so, it is invalid, or else put them in the HashMap.

Comment: @FuadRafid did you mean convert List<String> lines into a HashMap? In this case, this will throw duplicate key error isn't?

Comment: Hashmap doesn't throw duplicate key error, it just replaces the value. I have posted an answer with the code. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to look for duplicate keys and values in a Hashmap, which makes it easier.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String delimiter = ";";
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("somefile.txt")); 
        lines.forEach(line -> checkAndPutInMap(line,map,delimiter));
        lines.close();

    }

    private static void checkAndPutInMap(String line, Map<String,String> map, String delimiter) {
        String document = line.split(delimiter)[0];
        String typeOfDoc = line.split(delimiter)[1];
        if (map.containsKey(document) && !map.get(document).equals(typeOfDoc)) {
            ...create object to show that error on grid...
        }
        else
            map.put(document, typeOfDoc));
    }
}
```